# How to find different centers of various arcs in a almost circular hole using OpenCV?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a photo of a hole. I am currently assuming that the hole is not a perfect circle, and hence I need to find the change in dimension of the work. Now I was thinking of taking three 30 degrees arcs and find the distance from the centres of those arcs and the centre of the circle (which I will find using Hough circles) and take the mean of those values. Which is what I need for my research. I am attaching a sample photo of one of the holes that I have drilled. Any help will be helpful.

[image: Sample Photo Here]

Comment: start by detecting the inner contour and  split it into arcs then  fit each to circle to find centers .

Comment: @Ziri can you give me pointers on how to fit the circle part? Can you elaborate more on it? thanks

Comment: Once your have the Arcs you can apply RANSAC circle fitting : https://github.com/aerolalit/RANSAC-Algorithm

Comment: @Ziri I am also having trouble splitting the arcs? The only way I can think of is to take a minEnclosed circle like below and then split it into 30 deg increments and take those, but won't that actually give us the arc with respect to the actual circle and not the actual arc? I am not sure abt this part.

Comment: Enclosing circle is not what you'are looking for if you need accurate results . I suggest eliminating those defected (non-arc) regions from the inner contour using the distance from the centroid  to the edge, then split it into arcs.

Comment: you are suggesting taking the centre of the hole using hough circles?

Comment: Yes Hough circle or circle fitting . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59158136/how-to-split-a-contour-in-to-open-arcs-in-opencv  ; this answer is right but if the reason of splitting is accuracy you'll end up with less accuracy if you include those non-arc regions.  --> so eliminate them first.

Comment: If you eliminate those non-arc regions and your shape is not a perfect circle  you can calculate the centroid as well https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid

Comment: okay will try and get back to you on this

Answer (score 2):

An idea is to threshold then find contours and filter using the largest contour area. From here we use [`cv2.minEnclosingCircle()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=minenclosingcircle#minenclosingcircle) to find the center `(x,y)` point and the radius. Here's the largest contour highlighted in green

[image]

Now we simply find the minimum enclosing circle around the contour to determine the center point. Here's the result

[image]

the `(x,y)` coordinate

```
176.53846740722656 174.33653259277344
```

Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

for c in cnts:
    (x,y), radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
    cv2.circle(image,(int(x),int(y)),int(radius),(35,255,12),3)
    cv2.circle(image,(int(x),int(y)),1,(35,255,12),2)
    print(x,y)
    break

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: can u find more than one min enclosing circle using this function ??

Comment: No this approach is with the assumption that there is only one hole in the image

Comment: there is only one hole in the image but the hole is not exactly circular and hence I need the arcs as described in the question to get my data

Comment: I don't think im understanding your question correctly. Could you add an expected output image?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a hole you might use a specific color of the background behind your "object". So it should not be a problem to segment the actual shape:

[image]

and walk through all the points to find the most distant pairs (so you can find the diameter). With that being said you can find, for example, the centre of the circle you a looking for. Just did a quick test:

[image]

Sorry, no code to show. I'm not using OpenCV here, but you say any help is helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
import random

ConvexityDefectPoint = []

# load image as color to draw
img = cv2.imread('YourImagePath\\test.jpg' , 
cv2.IMREAD_COLOR )
#convert to gray
gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#threshold
ret,thresh1= cv2.threshold(gray,29,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh1,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
#find the biggest contour
contour_sizes = [(cv2.contourArea(contour), contour) for contour in contours]
biggest_contour = max(contour_sizes, key=lambda x: x[0])[1]
#draw the bigest contour
cv2.drawContours(img,biggest_contour,-1,(0,255,0),3)
# compute the center of the contour using moment
M = cv2.moments(biggest_contour)
cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
# draw the centroid
cv2.circle(img, (cX, cY), 7, (0, 255, 255), -1)
#Get convexity defect points
hull = cv2.convexHull(biggest_contour,returnPoints = False)
defects = cv2.convexityDefects(biggest_contour,hull)

for i in range(defects.shape[0]):
    s,e,f,d = defects[i,0]
    start = tuple(biggest_contour[s][0])
    end = tuple(biggest_contour[e][0])
    far = tuple(biggest_contour[f][0])
    ConvexityDefectPoint.append(far)
    #cv2.line(img,start,end,[0,255,0],2)
    cv2.circle(img,far,5,[0,0,255],-1)

# fit ellipse to the selected points.
(x, y), (MA, ma), angle = cv2.fitEllipse(np.array(ConvexityDefectPoint))
# draw the ellipse center
cv2.circle(img, (int(x), int(y)), 7, (0, 0, 255), -1)

# Draw the center using moment ( outliers eliminated)
M = cv2.moments(np.array(ConvexityDefectPoint))
cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
cv2.circle(img, (cX, cY), 7, (0, 255, ), -1)

cv2.imshow('Display',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This is just one of many possible methods you can use to calculate the centroid

- 1 using the moment
- 2 eliminate outliers using convexity defect and fit ellipse
- using moment with new data points (outliers eliminated)
- Result

[image]

- Farther improvement :

  eliminate outliers by iterating through the contour and detect arcs & non arcs

Comment: do you have any links on how to detect arcs and non-arcs. The only thing I can think of is to take the distance of one point on the contour and compare it to the previous one and see if the error is acceptable. I am sure there is a better way