# How to split a contour in to open arcs in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have the image below and I need to split the contour to create various 30 degrees arc which I then need to fit a circle through. The only thing I don't know how to split a contour. I am doing this in python. Any help is apperciated[image]

Comment: why do you need those arcs? you can fit a circle in the entire contour. and what is your problem in splitting the contour? I mean you have the points. what else can you wish for?

Comment: It looks like you have made some progress finding the contour shown in blue. Can you post the source image and the code that you used to find that contour? That would be really helpful in answering this question.

Answer (score 4):

This answer explains how to split the contour into 12 slices. There are three steps in this answer:

```
1. Find contours
2. Find the region that constitutes a slice
3. Test whether the contour point lies in that slice.
```

This is the code that I used to find the contour:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
import random
img = cv2.imread('/home/stephen/Desktop/cluv0.jpg')
h, w, _ = img.shape
low = np.array([99,130,144])
high = np.array([132,255,255])
mask = cv2.inRange(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV), low, high)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contour = contours[0]
center, radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(contour)
center = tuple(np.array(center, int))
```

This is the code that I used to find the divisions:

```
distance = 2*max(img.shape)
for i in range(divisions):
    # Get some start and end points that slice the image into pieces (like a pizza)
    x = math.sin(2*i*math.pi/divisions) * distance + center[0]
    y = math.cos(2*i*math.pi/divisions) * distance + center[1]    
    x2 = math.sin(2*(i+1)*math.pi/divisions) * distance + center[0]
    y2 = math.cos(2*(i+1)*math.pi/divisions) * distance + center[1]    
    xMid = math.sin(2*(i+.5)*math.pi/divisions) * 123 + center[0]
    yMid = math.cos(2*(i+.5)*math.pi/divisions) * 123 + center[1]

    top = tuple(np.array((x,y), int))
    bottom = tuple(np.array((x2,y2), int))
    midpoint = tuple(np.array((xMid,yMid), int))
```

[image: slices]

To test whether the contour point lies in the slice, I made a temporary mask and drew the slice in white. Then, I checked if the point was in a white region in the masked image:

```
# Create a mask and draw the slice in white
mask = np.zeros((h,w), np.uint8)    
cv2.line(mask, center, top, 255, 1)
cv2.line(temp_image, center, top, (255,0,0), 3)
cv2.line(mask, center, bottom, 255, 1)
cv2.floodFill(mask, None, midpoint, 255)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.waitKey()


# Iterate through the points in the contour
for contour_point in contour:
    x,y = tuple(contour_point[0])
    # Check if the point is in the white section
    if mask[y,x] == 255:
        cv2.circle(img, (x,y), 3, color, 3)
for i in range(25):
    vid_writer.write(cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR))
```

This gif shows the slices:

[image: pizza]

This is the output image:

[image: output]

Comment: In the above method you are taking the centre of a circle using minEnclosing Circle() and then splitting the contours. What I actually need from my code is to find the difference in the centre of the hole( through min enclosing circle) and various arcs of the hole( through splitting and fitting a circle to the arcs). My question is won't the centre of the circle effect where the centre of the arc is. If this is true then my arcs and hole centre will be aligned. I may be wrong about this.

Comment: Can you edit your original questions so that it includes this new information?

Comment: @KshitijPatil I added some code that explains how to draw a triangle of white on a black background.