# Is there any way for finding the center of the closed contour in opencv-python?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to find the measurements of the attached ring [Actual ring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JWon.png). But I'm getting stuck in particular finding the center of the contour. It will be appreciated if anyone could help me in that case [edged contour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvq1x.jpg).

If you think that any other way will be the best for me then please suggest me.

Comment: You can use  contour moments to find centdroid.               Check my answer  here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59099931/how-to-find-different-centers-of-various-arcs-in-a-almost-circular-hole-using-op?noredirect=1#comment104562497_59099931

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the **tour** (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help). Users are much more likely to help if you (1) show some research effort on your own (Google and StackOverflow searches), (2) learn what are appropriate questions for this forum and how to ask them, (3) show your images and (4) provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example to your specific problem.